# Woocommerce sort by price + products without prices at the end

Tags: wordpress, sorting, woocommerce

I'm trying to sort prices in woocommerce, that products which don't have one will be added in the end of sorting.

My function looks like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
  $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    if ( 'sort-price' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'CASE WHEN meta_value_num<1 THEN meta_value_num=99999 END ASC,meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '_price';

    }
```

After regenerating products lookup tables with this function sorting goes like:

```
1Category[1€] 1Category[2€] 1Category[No price] 2Category[1€]
```

Why second category products don't sorting properly?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?